How to test for Warning using ERT?
I want to check for a warning but not sure how to go about it.
My warning is:
Warning (my-func-file-not-found): /path/to/somefile.txt

This is created with display-warning 'my-func-file-not-found.
I have tried this:
(should (with-temp-buffer
            (my-func "init/nf")
            (search-forward "file-not-found" nil t)))

and this
(should-error (my-func "init/nf") :type 'my-func-file-not-found )


https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Do you have a function that is supposed to produce the warning under certain circurmstances and you are trying to test that indeed that is the case? If so, you should provide the function (or maybe a simplified example of one) that you are trying to test and specify under what circurmstances it should produce the warning.

@NickD Glad to see you here again :) . I have a big function and inside that function I have a dolist that checks to make sure the files exist. If the files do not exist then produce a warning. I want to make sure that warning is being produced when I run (my-func "path/to/no/file") how do I test for this with ERT ?

Here's some code (as babel source blocks in an Org mode file, but you can extract them and run them in an Elisp file instead) - I hope it's self-explanatory, but I have to post-and-run, so I will add some verbiage later on.
* Code                                                                                                        :noexport:

Define the function to test:

#+name: my-func
#+begin_src elisp 
  (defun my-func (file)
    (if (not (file-exists-p file))
        (display-warning 'my-func-file-not-found file)
      ;; else file exists: do something with it - here I just return the string "yes"
      "yes"))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: my-func
: my-func

Write the test:

#+name: my-func-test
#+begin_src elisp
  (require 'ert)

  (defun check-for-warning (msg)
    (with-current-buffer "*Warnings*"
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (search-forward msg nil t)))

  (ert-deftest test-my-func/warning-produced ()
    "Call my-func with non-existent file and check that the warning is produced."
    (let ((fname "/some/non/existent/path"))
      ;;; This (killing a buffer) is something that tests are *NOT* supposed to do,
      ;;; but I can't think of a clean way to *test* a side-effect producing function like `display-warning'.
      ;; if the *Warnings* buffer exists, kill it.
      (condition-case x
        (kill-buffer "*Warnings*")
        ('error t))
      
      ;; run the function to test
      (my-func fname)
      ;; check that the side-effect has happened
      (should (check-for-warning (format "Warning (my-func-file-not-found): %s" fname)))))

#+end_src

Run the test:
#+name: run-tests
#+begin_src elisp
 (ert "test-my-func/")
#+end_src

